# How to get notified when the status bar height changes?

Tags: iphone

Does the OS send notifications when the status bar height changes? For example that fat in-call status bar?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Your app delegate can implement these methods:

- `-application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:`
- `-application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:`

and these local notifications will also be sent to the default notification center:

- `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`
- `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`