# How to handle UI while starting skype call?

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

How to handle app ui while starting skype call.
at now my app UI move down when skype call notification shows on status bar.
I don't want this.
anyone how to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything to stop it. It is a system UI much like a phone call coming in. The best you can do is adapt your UI to handle the change in size to reduce the effect of the increased bar size.

---

In response to your comment. You can get a notification when the status bar is going to change size. As far as I can tell this is the only "official" way to handle call notifications especially pre iOS 8. This status bar size change is usually when a user is on a call but still using your app/ background VOIP is a similar thing.

Comment: but how to handle event for adjust ui when skype call coming in?

Comment: @VinodJadhav: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944411/how-to-get-notified-when-the-status-bar-height-changes).