# Understanding the magic number hidden in the statusbar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, statusbar

To get the `height` of the statusbar of the iOS application, we do

```
let height = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
print(height)
```

and this returns `20.0` in a normal situation.

If the statusbar has *expanded* due to in-call, or personal hotspot, condition, this will return `40.0`.

Now let us say that we have a `NavigationController` with a `UICollectionView` built-in. And we're trying to figure out the location where the `contentOffset` of the collection view points to.

```
let contentOffset = self.collectionView!.contentOffset
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

With a normal statusbar, the results are:

> contentOffset: (0.0, -64.0)
>
> statusBarHeight: 20.0

Meaning that the `NavigationBar`'s height is `64.0`.

And with expanded statusbar:

> contentOffset: (0.0, -64.0)
>
> statusBarHeight: 40.0

Notice the contentOffset is still `(0.0, -64.0)` but not `(0.0, -84.0)`. This means that there's *unreachable space* behind the expanded statusbar. And I believe there's no way we can figure out the actual size of this *unreachable space*.

We can only guess it is `20.0` since we already know this number in practice.

[image]

[image]

So let say we want to draw a nice view right below the statusbar. But using the information given by `statusBarHeight`, we can't do that since the whole view will shrink it's height by *magical* 20px that we don't know about.

If we want to place a view of frame `(0, statusBarHeight, 100, 100)`, this will be placed right below the status bar if the status bar is in the **normal** state. But if the status bar has **expanded**, this will fail because now the `statusBarHeight` is `40`.

Now we have to add the *magic number* like below:

```
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight - 20, width: 100, height: 100)
```

**So my question is:**

*How do we compute this magic number?*

Answer (score 2):

Your app delegate can implement these methods:

- `-application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:`
- `-application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:`

and these local notifications will also be sent to the default notification center:

- `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`
- `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`

Here you go to `statusBarHeight` for compute magic number

More check this  [Get notification status Bar Height change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944534/4415445)

Comment: Yes these methods will give you information about `when` does this change happens, and the height will be `40.0` if expanded. But I want to know how much the entire view did shrink in it's height which is not 40.0 it's 20.0.

Comment: did you  test anything that goes status bar 20 but not printed. for example recording or anything else . more check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888517/get-iphone-status-bar-height?rq=1